# How to send existing SOAP Request to Existing WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a problem, I have a SOAP request envelope like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:str="http://string.soap.webservices.invent.telkom.co.id"><soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
    <str:PhyStatus soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <ip xsi:type="xsd:string">172.20.20.123</ip>
        <slot xsi:type="xsd:string">4</slot>
        <port xsi:type="xsd:string">33</port>
    </str:PhyStatus>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And i have WSDL that has service with differents parameters but same numbers as the inputs.
In java, how can i send that SOAP request to this WSDL?

For your info, this is the output (SOAP response) that i want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://string.soap.webservices.invent.telkom.co.id" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:PhyStatusResponse>
        <PhyStatusReturn xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Struct">
            <AdminStatus xsi:type="xsd:string">Active</AdminStatus>
            <LinkStatus xsi:type="xsd:string">Activating</LinkStatus>
            <LineProfile xsi:type="xsd:string">ADSL LINE PROFILE 10</LineProfile>
        </PhyStatusReturn>
    </ns1:PhyStatusResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: FYI, you never send a request to a WSDL. A WSDL is just an XML file that describes a service. You are sending a request to a service which is described by a WSDL.

Comment: Do you use any libs for working with web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any http client to post your soap message to the service which is the url remove "?wsdl"